# Images disappear after saving a sugarcrm email template

Tags: sugarcrm

When I save an email template in sugarcrm, some of the images are displayed while some disappear. The background color is also missing after saving the template. If I compose the mail and send it without saving it will be displayed properly. Please let me know if anyone has the solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder about the underlying HTML there. Sugar uses a WYSIWYG editor when composing emails (it's the commonly used TinyMCE actually). If you copied a relative URL for the image it may not be storing properly. I'd also check your browser version and version of SugarCRM.

Another thought - since it happens when saving the template, what's the URL for the image look like? Anything unusual that might be parsed out accidentally?

It would probably help if you posted the HTML behind the email template before and after saving the template.

Comment: I found where the problem is but not the solution yet. When I save the template, background-image: url('xyz.com/image1.png') is being saved as background-image: url(

Comment: Could you edit the HTML directly to use double quotes instead of single quotes? Not a good answer, but maybe a work around. Might be best to submit a bug with SugarCRM about this.